# Pass value to be inserted in div to open window

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to open a new window in the same tab and pass some html code to be inserted in a div section of the new open window. I am having trouble to pass the data as shown below:

Parent javascript:

```
function popupPlace() {
   var mywindow = window.open('Details.html','_self');
   mywindow.dataFromParent = placeListAll; 
   mywindow.init();
 }
```

Child javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dataFromParent;  
    function init() {
    document.getElementById('Place').innerHTML=dataFromParent;

    }
</script>
```

The init method is not being called.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're not talking about a new tab in the same window? Anymway the better way for you to send data in your new tab seems to pass it as url param :

```
window.open('Details.html?data=some-data-maybe-b64-encoded','_self');
```

Then you can get it in child with :

```
var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
var data = urlParams.get('data'));
```

finally :

```
//parent
function popupPlace() {
   //encoding to be able to store html in uri
   var htmlForChild = encodeURIComponent("<p>Content for Children</p>"); 
   var mywindow = window.open('Details.html?data=' + htmlForchild, '_self');
   mywindow.dataFromParent = placeListAll; 
   mywindow.init();
}

//child
function init() {
    var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    document.getElementById('Place').innerHTML=decodeURIComponent(urlParams);
}
```

Comment: But why can't I change the innerHTML of the child with the data variable as per your example?

Comment: you can, see my edited answer (i've not tested the code in browser so maybe there's some little errors, but the idea still here). Btw when you have an id in your html the element target is automatically represented by a variable named as the id, so you can access the "Place" element without getElementById using the generated var : "Place.innerHTML = ...".